# How to rotate hamburger menu icons on click

Tags: html, jquery, css, hamburger-menu

I have a problem with my hamburger menu, especially with the icons. My HTML looks like this:

```html
 <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
 <header class="IndexHeader">
   <nav class="navigation">
       <label class="Hamburger" for="check">&#9776;</label>
       <label class="schliessen" for="check">&#9932;</label>
       <ul class="IndexNavliste">
           a list...
       </ul>  
    </nav>            
 </header>
```

I want my `.schliessen` label to rotate 180 degrees when I click on the `.Hamburger` label, so that it is like an animation effect. I tried it like this with jQuery:

```js
$(".Hamburger").click(function(){
   $(".schliessen").css("transform","rotate(180deg)");
});
```

That didn't really work for me. Also, I think I need a transition in it so that I really can see it when I click the label. I also tried to do it in the CSS directly so when my checkbox is checked. That works but I couldn't see the animation and my hover effect didn't work anymore after that...

```css
.Hamburger{
  display: block;
  transition: 500ms;
}
.schliessen{
  transition: 500ms;
}
.schliessen:hover{
  color: black;
}
#check:checked + .IndexHeader .navigation .Hamburger{
  display: none;
}
#check:checked + .IndexHeader .navigation .schliessen{
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: See if this helps :) https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/XWjBXRY?editors=1111 But it works for initial render only.. Trying to fix this :)

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately that isn't working for me... the solution with rotateZ in your codepen doesn't work right I think?

Comment: I was debugging that ! That's not the original one... Try now :)

Comment: Ok thank you. Your solution in codepen is exactly what I want and it looks nice. However, in my code it doesn't work...Do you have any idea why? Or is it maybe a browser problem, although I tested it in Chrome and Edge...?

Comment: .. Actually I also changed the CSS a bit...You need to update that also ...

Comment: Shall I add my answer for you to accept it if it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helps me a lot and it works now.

Comment: Oh Dear ! Being a developer I feel peace in helping fellow developers...Pleasure is all mine . Even we learn things from answering other's... Otherwise I no longer use JQuery now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `transition` and `transform:rotate("180deg")` is happening because `transform` never gets a new value from first click onwards on Hamburger. To overcome that I have added and removed classes on clicks.

Have also removed un-necessary CSS and added what is required for this problem :

Here is the working code:

[codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/XWjBXRY?editors=1111](http://%20codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/XWjBXRY?editors=1111)